# PHP form once submitted allow user input again to produce new values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

When a form is filled in and submitted and the user is taken to the .php specified in the form, and their inputs are sent over using POST and are now echoed out for the User to see their inputs, is it possible on the same page to have buttons or radio checks that can do different operations to their inputs depending on which one has been clicked?

As i gather this isn't possible to do with javascript and php as one is serverside one if browserside. And using a new form, also ajax, seem to use POST call that loses all their original values that were being echoed?

Any ideas as to if there is a solution and the best way to implement it?

An example is a calorie calculator, The users input of height, weight, etc gets submitted then the values are used to calculate the calories. So the value is echoed - but on the same page it is echoed the user can now click a button for dividing the calories into 50% carbs 40% protein 10% fats or another button 40 40 20, etc.

Comment: you can echo the values on multiple places in the newly generated webpage (the php result of form submit), just use `<?php echo $_POST['key']; ?>` where needed. You can also render another form on that page which has prefilled given values. That new form can be fully handled by javascript or with hidden input fields it can be resend to render whole different page while keeping submitted values from first form.

Comment: @insider could you help me with the code of how I would do that, without losing the existing values that the user inputed? I have tried both javascript buttons and I am unable to get the value into php to know which buttons been clicked to then do calculations, I have also tried hidden fields.

Comment: the answer given by Nosyara is what you need, try to build on it. To find out what button was pressed, use name attributes on them (different name for each button) and check which name is present in $_POST. This will tell you which button was pressed. Or javascript can takeover handling of those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your problem is - the page refreshed (or different page shown) and you want to preserve values inside input fields from previous state. You may do it as following:

```
<form ...>
   Weight:<input name="weight" value="<?php $_REQUEST['weight']?>"/>
   ...
```

Then when you calling this page by form sumbit - it will show same values in fields.

Upd:

JavaScript simplified solution:

html:

```
Weight: <input type="text" id="weight" />
Calories: <input type="text" id="calories" />
Result:  <span id="result"></span>
<a href="javascript:calculate1()">Calulate formula 1</a> 
<a href="javascript:calculate2()">Calulate formula 2</a>
```

js part:

```
function calculate1(){
  var w = document.getElementById('weight');
  var cal = document.getElementById('calories');  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = w / cal;
}

function calculate2(){
  var w = document.getElementById('weight');
  var cal = document.getElementById('calories');  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = cal / w;
}
```

And of course you can style <a> as a button.

Comment: No, I want form.html + calculate.php's form -> redirect to -> calculate.php and show values but also have buttons to generate different results while still on calculate.php

Comment: Use javascript. I adding another answer with JS solution